# Low energy consumption mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, optimization

I am developing an universal app that will always be active in retail stores (as guided access app).

I would like to enable some kind of low power consumption mode for non-trade hours, but could not find much information.

What options do I have to diminish the power consumption while my app is active?

**EDIT**

The app only shows a web view I do not control.

I was thinking about dimming the screen, which surely will make a difference. But I was wondering if there is anything else that can be done

Comment: You can dim the screen, but generally if your app isn't doing anything then it won't use much energy. You can use the energy profile Instrument to look at your apps energy usage. Things like playing video or animations will use energy

Comment: It already uses minimum energy consumption (0 out of 20 in instruments). But I thought dimming the screen would help, and was wondering if there are any other strategies I do not know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Apples docs says

> There’s no single solution for conserving energy on a device. Numerous
>   technologies and operations influence how energy is used:

As you said "The app only shows a web view" that you do not control so most of the optimization you can do is on the network side and WKWebView do most of this for us but can explore more areas also like scheduling your notification based on priority, colour also affect how much energy app is using, etc..

Back to webview
 You can batch your transactions [How to batch transactions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/DeferNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH18-SW2)

If your webview content is not changing frequently you can cache those and use that instead of doing network calls and have a refresh button so only refresh when the user clicks. 
In poor/No network instead of fetching first than showing error check SCNetworkReachability its save unnecessary network calls, use pause/ play mechanism while downloading so don't have to download same data again.

Basically, there are so many areas you can check based on your app usability and improve it checkOut Apples doc [Energy Efficiency and the User Experience](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH3-SW1) and mainly [Energy and Networking](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/EnergyandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH16-SW1)